# Finding/Printing Variables that Correspond to the Maximum Output of a List

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am very new to Mathematica and been having a problem that is frustrating because I feel that there must be a simple solution which I just can't grasp.

Essentially, I am looking to automatically align an image that has a certain pattern (something like a bunch of repeating diamond shapes) with a grid of that pattern. I am calculating the overlap product - trying to find the maximum value possible when multiplying my own grid with the image at different positions to find the best alignment.

To do so, I made a Table with variables 'x' and 'y' giving the many different translations of the grid through`{x,-10,10}`and`{y,-10,10}`to end up with a big list of the resulting overlap products.
Now, it is easy enough to find the maximum of this list with `Max[list]`. However, to continue on to my next calculation I want to know exactly which values of x and y correspond to this maximum product - this is the part I have been struggling with.

Is it possible to somehow print the corresponding x/y variables alongside each result of my overlap calculation so I can easily use those values in the next steps of my routine?

Comment: There is `MaximalBy`. But why don't you try out `ImageAlign[baseImage, patternImage, TransformationClass -> "Translation"]` instead?

Comment: For a function `f[x, y]` that evaluates to a scalar, `MaximalBy[Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y]}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}], 1], Last]`